# About the code comments for bootstrapping issues in collections.py and _abcoll.py (python 2.7.3)

Tags: python

I am reading the source the collections module. The modue is the combination of the two files:  collections.py and _abcoll.py.
Here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) of the module, and it contains links to the source code.

In the beginning of collections.py:

```
__all__ = ['Counter', 'deque', 'defaultdict', 'namedtuple', 'OrderedDict']
# For bootstrapping reasons, the collection ABCs are defined in _abcoll.py.
# They should however be considered an integral part of collections.py.
from _abcoll import *
import _abcoll
__all__ += _abcoll.__all__
...
```

I don't quite understand what's the actual 'bootstrapping reasons', since in _abcoll.py:

```
 6 DON'T USE THIS MODULE DIRECTLY!  The classes here should be imported
 7 via collections; they are defined here only to alleviate certain
 8 bootstrapping issues.  Unit tests are in test_collections.
 9 """
10 
11 from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
12 import sys
13 
14 __all__ = ["Hashable", "Iterable", "Iterator",
15            "Sized", "Container", "Callable",
16            "Set", "MutableSet",
17            "Mapping", "MutableMapping",
18            "MappingView", "KeysView", "ItemsView", "ValuesView",
19            "Sequence", "MutableSequence",
20            ]
...
```

the `_abc.__all__` contains all the classes definitions in this file, and in collections.py, it imports * from `_abcoll` and append `_abcoll.__all__` to its own `__all__`. I didn't get it about why this way can 'alleviate certain bootstrapping issues'.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in older versions of `os.py`, e.g. [this one](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f3ce3e874a58/Lib/os.py#l446):

```
from _abcoll import MutableMapping # Can't use collections (bootstrap)
```

Apparently, `collections` indirectly requires `os` (probably for the tests at the end of the module, where some pickling is done, and maybe elsewhere) so there'd be a circular dependency without the `_abcoll` module.

(Note that in Python >=3.3, there's a separate [`collections.abc`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) module.)